# Bash script that needs root only runs when I type exit!

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I have successfully made a bash script that needs root, permission, which I can run as root! But, the script only runs when I am using the terminal as root and if I type exit, it runs.  When I type :

```
bash lights_infinity.sh
```

The terminal does nothing. Why is this so and is it normal? The code is

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo su
while true
do
    sudo -k setleds -D +caps < /dev/console
    sleep 0.1
    sudo -k setleds -D +caps < /dev/console
    sleep 0.1
    sudo -k setleds -D -caps < /dev/console
    sleep 0.1
done
```

Do I need to remove the sudo commands?

Comment: yes, just sudo /path/to/script . Put a shebang at the top `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: `sudo su` is opening a new shell

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini , Surprise, surprise, when I run it without the use of sudo su, it asks for my password, and opens nothing new

Comment: question: when is this loop suppose to end? Oh: and the one I posted below seems to run with a single "sudo" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $EUID -ne 0 ]]; then
   echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi
while true
do
    setleds -D +caps < /dev/console
    sleep 0.1
    setleds -D +caps < /dev/console
    sleep 0.1
    setleds -D -caps < /dev/console
    sleep 0.1
done
```

and do this:

```
sudo lights_infinity.sh
```

(add the `-k` if you want to kill the 15 minute time-frame for sudo but should not be needed)

---

The reason you need the "exit" is due to the "sudo su" you used. That opens an extra shell you need to "exit".

---

- extra: check for "root" at the beginning of the file. If this runs for 15 minutes it might error out(not sure); if so add "sudo" to the "setleds" and it will stop and ask the password.
- extra2: 3 times "setleds -D +(/-)caps < /dev/console
  sleep 0.1" looks better when you use a function. And the while loop will look better if it has a nicer exit than control-x.

Comment: root@ILOVEROBLOX123:/home/meshak/Desktop# sudo sh lights_infinity.sh
lights_infinity.sh: 2: lights_infinity.sh: [[: not found        **And I have my keyboard light doing a light show! Thank you!**

Comment: it works for me???  (`~/leds$ ./lights_infinity.sh` shows `This script must be run as root`)

Comment: @Rinzwind you need to run it with sudo at the start. So `$ sudo ./lights_infinity.sh`